# Not able to tag friends on facebook when share photo using android:facebook-sdk:4.1.0

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I share link on facebook with taggable friends it work fine and when share photos with taggable friends its not work.Display only photos on facebook without tagged friends.

Code that i used to share photos on facebook.

```
  ArrayList<String> friendsIds = new ArrayList<>();
  List<SharePhoto> photoList = new ArrayList<>();

            Bitmap image1 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.offer_1);

            SharePhoto photo1 = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setBitmap(image1)
                    .setCaption(mRestaurantName)
                    .build();

            Bitmap image2 = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.offer_placeholder_image);

            SharePhoto photo2 = new SharePhoto.Builder()
                    .setCaption(mRestaurantName + " Testing ")
                    .setBitmap(image2)
                    .build();

            photoList.add(photo1);
            photoList.add(photo2);


            ShareContent content = new SharePhotoContent.Builder()
                                              .addPhotos(photoList)
                                            .setPeopleIds(friendsIds)
                    .build();

            ShareApi.share(content, new FacebookCallback<Sharer.Result>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Sharer.Result result) {

                    if (result != null)
                        showToast(getString(R.string.successfully_post_on_facebook));

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    showToast(getString(R.string.you_have_cancelled_th_request));
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException e) {

                    showToast(e.getMessage());

                }
            });
```

Comment: Your code looks correct. However, tagging is only supported for Open Graph and Links for now. We are looking into ways for adding support to photos.

Comment: @ifaour thanks,Is any way to post image with tagging friends.

Comment: Maybe using the [`POST /{USER-ID}/photos`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/photos/#Creating), but this would require requesting the `publish_stream` permission which may not be the best user experience.

Comment: @ifaour Is it now possible? Using version 4.10.0 ?

Comment: @ifaour: Is it now possible? Using version 4.24.0, Its not working still

Comment: @ifaour is it now supported?